# how to cut the last field using cut linux bash?

Tags: linux, bash

**Hello everyone i want to know to cut the last field with separator : 
without knowing how many fields that i have any ideas please . 
is there any option for command cut .**

Answer (score 6):

You can revert the string and then print 1st character. Itself *cut* can't work from backwards.

```
echo "Your string ABC" | rev | cut -c 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Awk is the right tool for this. Try :

```
ls -lh  | awk '{ print $NF }'
```